# Need to retrieve latest 7 days coil activity for each system from coil failed date along with need to add rank based on system and Logdate in Python

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have below dataset. I am trying to get latest 7 days data for each system from coil failed date and also I want to add rank based on system and coil failed date.

| sys_no |  | log_date |  | tot_norm_scans |  | fail_reason |  | tot_fail_scans |  | case_num |  | coil_fail_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8343 |  | 2022-01-12 |  | 12 |  | code001 |  | 2 |  | 23476 |  | 2022-01-13 |
| 8343 |  | 2022-01-08 |  | 0 |  | code001 |  | 5 |  | 23477 |  | 2022-01-13 |
| 8343 |  | 2022-01-08 |  | 0 |  | code003 |  | 3 |  | 25676 |  | 2022-01-13 |
| 8343 |  | 2022-01-02 |  | 5 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  | 29476 |  | 2022-01-13 |
| 8346 |  | 2022-01-01 |  | 45 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  | 23476 |  | 2022-01-13 |
| 8392 |  | 2021-12-21 |  | 32 |  | code002 |  | 5 |  | 25489 |  | 2022-12-24 |
| 90081 |  | 2021-12-01 |  | 2 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  | 27021 |  | 2022-12-04 |
| 20892 |  | 2021-12-01 |  | 0 |  | code001 |  | 15 |  | 29546 |  | 2022-12-02 |
| 20892 |  | 2021-12-01 |  | 0 |  | code002 |  | 12 |  | 29546 |  | 2022-12-02 |

I am looking for last 7 days data for each system from coil failed date. we my have one or more coil failure(case_number). I need to retrieve data for each case_number in case we have more than one case_number. Also while selecting 7 days data, I want all failed reasons data to be also covered, example 2nd and 3rd row for same date we have 2 errors I want them to consider as is. Final data I am expecting to be like below

| sys_no |  | log_date |  | tot_norm_scans |  | fail_reason |  | tot_fail_scans |  | case_num |  | coil_fail_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8343 |  | 2022-01-12 |  | 12 |  | code001 |  | 2 |  | 23476 |  | 2022-01-13 |
| 8343 |  | 2022-01-08 |  | 0 |  | code001 |  | 5 |  | 23477 |  | 2022-01-13 |
| 8343 |  | 2022-01-08 |  | 0 |  | code003 |  | 3 |  | 25676 |  | 2022-01-13 |
| 8343 |  | 2022-02-06 |  | 5 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  | 29476 |  | 2022-01-13 |
| 8346 |  | 2022-01-04 |  | 45 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  | 23476 |  | 2022-01-13 |
| 8346 |  | 2022-01-02 |  | 22 |  | 3 |  | 0 |  | 23476 |  | 2022-01-13 |
| 8346 |  | 2022-01-01 |  | 12 |  | code003 |  | 0 |  | 23476 |  | 2022-01-13 |
| 8346 |  | 2022-01-01 |  | 10 |  | code001 |  | 0 |  | 23476 |  | 2022-01-13 |
| 8392 |  | 2021-12-22 |  | 32 |  | code002 |  | 5 |  | 25489 |  | 2022-12-24 |
| 8392 |  | 2021-12-21 |  | 32 |  | code002 |  | 5 |  | 25489 |  | 2022-12-24 |
| 8392 |  | 2021-12-20 |  | 32 |  | code002 |  | 5 |  | 25489 |  | 2022-12-24 |
| 8392 |  | 2021-12-19 |  | 32 |  | code003 |  | 5 |  | 25489 |  | 2022-12-24 |
| 8392 |  | 2021-12-19 |  | 32 |  | code002 |  | 5 |  | 25489 |  | 2022-12-24 |
| 8392 |  | 2021-12-18 |  | 32 |  | code002 |  | 5 |  | 25489 |  | 2022-12-24 |
| 8392 |  | 2021-12-17 |  | 32 |  | code002 |  | 5 |  | 25489 |  | 2022-12-24 |
| 8392 |  | 2021-12-16 |  | 32 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  | 25489 |  | 2022-12-24 |
| 90081 |  | 2021-12-01 |  | 2 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  | 27021 |  | 2022-12-04 |
| 20892 |  | 2021-12-01 |  | 0 |  | code001 |  | 15 |  | 29546 |  | 2022-12-02 |
| 20892 |  | 2021-12-01 |  | 0 |  | code002 |  | 12 |  | 29546 |  | 2022-12-02 |

I am looking for above data. 7 days latest data from coil failed data by considering failed reason column with respect SRN and log date.

Along with above data I need a rank column that should rate by considering SRN only. rank should stay between 1 to 7 for each SRNs

|rank|
|....
|7|
|6|
|6|
|5|
|4|
|3|
|2|
|1|
|1|
|7|
|6|
|5|
|4|
|4|
|3|
|2|
|1|
|7|
|7|
|7|

I tried below codes but it didn't provide what I am expecting.

```
df = df.sort_values('log_date',ascending = False).groupby(['sys_no']).head(7)
df = .sort_values(by=['SRN','log_date'], ascending=False, ignore_index=True)

list1 = []
for srn in df['SRN'].unique().tolist():
    if len(df[df['SRN']== srn]) == 7:
        for num in range(7):
            list1.append((num+1))       
    elif len(df[df['SRN']== srn]) == 6:
         for num in range(6):
            list1.append((num+1)) 
    elif len(df[df['SRN']== srn]) == 5:
         for num in range(5):
            list1.append((num+1))
    elif len(df[df['SRN']== srn]) == 4:
         for num in range(4):
            list1.append((num+1))
    elif len(df[df['SRN']== srn]) == 3:
         for num in range(3):
            list1.append((num+1))
    elif len(df[df['SRN']== srn]) == 2:
         for num in range(2):
            list1.append((num+1))
    elif len(df[df['SRN']== srn]) == 1:
         for num in range(1):
            list1.append((num+1))
list1

df['rank'] = pd.Series(list1)
```

Above code gives latest 7 records instead of 7 days and ranking also with respect to record it took, it didn't consider rank per day as 1 instead it considers record length.

How to get the data as explained above?

Comment: In the expected data output example you're showing 8 instances of case number 25489, you want 7, correct?

Comment: since 19th Dec 2022 failed_reason is 2 different codes hence rows are 8 but days are 7 only

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, the way I understand this is you're looking for the latest 7 dates with associated "fail_reason" codes for each group (case number). Please clarify if it's not.

```
df_1=df_.groupby('case_num')['fail_reason'].unique()
df_=df_.join(df_1,rsuffix='_r',lsuffix='_l',on='case_num').drop('fail_reason_l',axis=1)

cols=df_.columns
df_group=df_.groupby(by='case_num')[cols].tail(7)
df_result=df_group.explode('fail_reason_r')
```